# Myriad fonts not showing up in Flash CS 3

Tags: fonts, flash-cs3

I am opening a .fla (CS 3) file to make some text update to an old file. It has Myriad Pro fonts, but i cant see the text at all in the fla file, it is not a matter of the text being buried in a deep movie clip and it is not a dynamic text.

I suspect that there is something to do with Myriad Pro fonts because i try opening a new clean file to type using the Myriad Pro fonts, it also show me white texts which i totally cant read (i have use black for the font).

I am able to Control F and find the text, but it also appear in white, which mean i cant see what i have edited unless and publish it.

Has anyone face this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

Same thing is happening to me today. Myriad, futura fonts are not showing up in Flash CS3. They work fine in photoshop....

Does this have something to do with the Windows Update that occurred last night?

Ugh!

Comment: This is not an answer, please leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here today. Trying to open recent CS4/5 flash file. Must be some update thing that is messing with the fonts.

EDIT: I just found this: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1117579

uninstall windows update kb2753842

Some more info here: http://graphics-unleashed.unleash.com/2012/12/windows-update-kb2753842-will-make-some.html